Do I need an Array? Trend-recognition
I don't get any further...
I want to recognize a trend and for this need to compare the lastLow and lastHigh to the Low and High before.
The High and Low I get from the ZigZag-library in TradingView.
https://www.tradingview.com/script/bzIRuGXC-ZigZag/
The indicator writes the Highs and Lows as pivots in an Array:
array<Pivot> pivots

and shows them as lable:
label       lb

How can I compare the lastHigh and lastLow to the one before and change if both are higher/lower i.e. the color of the background to green/red?
I tried to read out the array, but it doesn't even have a name.
export type ZigZag
    Settings     settings
    array<Pivot> pivots
    float        sumVol = 0
    Pivot        extend = na

export newInstance(series Settings settings = na) =>
    ZigZag result = ZigZag.new(na(settings) ? Settings.new() : settings, array.new<Pivot>())

Now I think if I could change it in a permanent Array or if I should go with a series and a calculation on every change.
Guess thats to high for me :)
Thanks for your advice!
Cassandra

something like this:
//@version=5
indicator("Zig Zag", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)

import TradingView/ZigZag/7 as ZigZagLib 

// Create Zig Zag instance from user settings.
var zigZag = ZigZagLib.newInstance(
  ZigZagLib.Settings.new(
      input.float(5.0, "Price deviation for reversals (%)", 0.00001, 100.0, 0.5, "0.00001 - 100"),
      input.int(10, "Pivot legs", 2),
      input(#2962FF, "Line color", display = display.data_window),
      input(true, "Extend to last bar", display = display.data_window),
      input(true, "Display reversal price", display = display.data_window),
      input(true, "Display cumulative volume", display = display.data_window),
      input(true, "Display reversal price change", inline = "priceRev", display = display.data_window),
      input.string("Absolute", "", ["Absolute", "Percent"], inline = "priceRev", display = display.data_window),
      true)
 )

// Update 'zigZag' object on each bar with new ​pivots, ​volume, lines, labels.
zigZag.update()


if zigZag.pivots.size() > 2 
    latestPiv = zigZag.pivots.last()
    previousPiv = zigZag.pivots.get(zigZag.pivots.size() - 2)  // or latestPiv[1]
    log.info("latest {0}", latestPiv.isHigh)
    log.info("previous {0}", previousPiv.isHigh)


I added a reply, but it shows above your answer... :)
